# Application.LoadLevel causes my game crash on Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I kill an enemy I want to go next level but the game crashes in Application.LoadLevel in my android device. In unity editor all it's right and loads next level but in android device crashes. How can I solve it? This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using Invector;

public class PuntosPistas_RA : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject Enemy4;
private bool doOnce4;
private GameObject Player;


void Start ()
{
    Enemy4 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy4");
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    Player.GetComponent<PuntosPistas>().Score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");

}
void Update()
{

    if (Enemy4.GetComponent<v_AIController> () != null) {
        if (Enemy4.GetComponent<v_AIController> ().currentHealth <= 0 && doOnce4 == false) {
            doOnce4 = true;

            Application.LoadLevel("map");
            Debug.Log("To map");

        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the error that appears in the Android device Monitor when I test it:

```
09-28 14:04:24.343: A/libc(31857): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x9c in tid 31879 (UnityMain)
09-28 14:04:24.486: W/ActivityManager(847):   Force finishing activity 1 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity
09-28 14:04:24.575: W/InputDispatcher(847): channel '35106e3 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
09-28 14:04:24.575: E/InputDispatcher(847): channel '35106e3 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-28 14:04:24.578: I/WindowState(847): WIN DEATH: Window{35106e3 u0 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}
09-28 14:04:24.579: W/InputDispatcher(847): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '35106e3 com.asm.NETPOINTBOA/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)'
```

Comment: How can I get it? In Unity console doesn't appear anything. It runs ok

Comment: Thanks! I've followed the tutorial and this is the crash log: 
09-18 21:08:11.161: A/libc(32316): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 32350 (UnityMain)
09-18 21:08:16.677: I/Choreographer(32316): Skipped 324 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-18 21:08:16.678: W/AudioTrack(32316): releaseBuffer() track 0xb85e9fc8 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting

Comment: Is there a script in the new scene that does a lot of work or  it might even be stuck in an endless loop?

Comment: I only have this script in my player to project the device camera in a plane: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
 public WebCamTexture mCamera = null;
 public GameObject plane;

 void Start ()
 {
  Debug.Log ("Script has been started");
  plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("PlayerCam");

  mCamera = new WebCamTexture ();
  plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = mCamera;
  mCamera.Play ();

 }

}

Comment: Yes I've an asset called Third Person Template but it works ok in the other scenes

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to Application.LoadLevel being an obsolete code type, it's been replaced by [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).

if using javascript add using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;, not sure if it's the same for C#.

UPDATE:
Ensure that in the build settings you have included the Map level and that it's in the correct order.  This would explain why it runs in editor and not when you build and run the copy.  Basically when you build it it doesn't know where to go.

Comment: Better yet.. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html as it looks like the crash could be saved by going Async...

Comment: using Application.LoadLevel should rectify the crash but it's always good to have a back up plan like using the Async version.

Comment: I've replaced it but it crashes again :(

Comment: Wait wait wait, thinking about it now, check your build settings to ensure that the map level you are trying to call is set up after the level you are running initially.

Comment: I've checked the build settings and it's ok

Comment: Ok, so build settings have all your levels in correct order, yet when you load Map it crashes on Android only correct?  And it's crashing with the same error as before you got rid of legacy code for loading levels?

Comment: @Phillipv20 I've write above the error that appears in the Android device Monitor when I test it.

Comment: add a debug.log above your load level,

Comment: so it's still running ok int he editor though correct?

Comment: I think I 've found the solution. I'm using WebCamTexture to display the telephone camera in a plane and it's producing the error

Comment: oh ok, well i'm glad you got it worked out and good luck in your en devour.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a camera instance (WebCamTexture) while you trying to load another scene!

You need to **call the Stop() method of WebCamTexture before you load a new scene**, otherwise the application will quit and throw an exception on Android.